# REACT JS: npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'G:\React app\package.json' and other errors?

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npm-install

I ran the command npm install command as shown in the tutorial and have followed the previous step as it is but the following errors are coming idk why?

npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path G:\React app/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'G:\React app\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-02-18T13_58_21_233Z-debug-0.log
PS G:\React app>

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GHfa.png)

Yesterday I tried npm audit fix --force but stil the problem was not solved. Please help!!!

Comment: You need a root-level `package.json` file. Either add one to `React app` or delete that `package-lock.json` at your top level and just open the `my-app` folder

Comment: Your `package.json` is in folder `my-app`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: yeah, I got that later thanks Matthew Herbst

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue but for me the mistake was being inside a folder that was not where I was working on so I had to cd back into the folder and I was able to run npm start and it worked.

Comment: yeah ,I got that later on.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).